# Unable to get min-height to work on table in Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox, css

I have an issue with min-height not working on my absolutely postioned table. But, I'm able to get it working in IE 6 using height (as i know IE 6 treats height like min-height)

Any clues on how I can get this working?

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:0;width:100%;min-height:100px; height: auto !important; height: 100px">
<tr>
<td> adawdaaw </td>
<td> fefsfs </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @user `height: auto !important;` is causing the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `height:100px` as this interpreted as minimum height on tables anyway.