# CSS min-height not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: css

I created a div tag with min-height and gave background color 'red'. but on mozilla firefox the height of the div not increasing when the content crosses min-height limit. heres my code:

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
ul {
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
    width:500px;
}

.b {
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

div {
    min-height:50px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:red;
}
--></style>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
        <li class="b">asdsad</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

its seeming the div height would have to be set to fit contents,but I don't know how else can I do that.if I don't use height then background-color can't be set.please tell me how can I fit the contents to the div as well as the background color would be red. 
(Don't know if I explained it clearly.so please ask me if you want to know more about the question.)

-Thanks.

***RESOLVED:*** thank you everybody for your kind answers.

Comment: why you not giving only height and clear both that div? Let me know?

Comment: sorry,I didn't understand what did you mean.could you please make me clear ?

Comment: what you need you have fixed li width and also it's parent width it seems in this div only pairs of li comes? please explain it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update your css like this:

```
div{min-height:50px;width:500px;background-color:red;overflow:hidden;}
```

`overflow:hidden;` added

Basically, that happens because of  `float:left` in `.b` class. That is how it works. Usually you can fix it by adding `overflow:hidden` to parent div or by adding an element with style="clear:both;" at the end of parent div.

You can search more info about it with 'CSS clearfix' keywords.

Comment: thanks a lot, that works ! I added overflow:hidden to 'div'.I'm gonna accept this answer 6 min later(thats what the message said). thanks for your help...

Answer (score 31):

On Firefox, `min-height` is not interpreted on `display: table(-*);` properties, juste try to use `height: 50px;` instead as it is interpreted as minimum height on tables.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875039/unable-to-get-min-height-to-work-on-table-in-firefox-3-6)

Comment: So you can use `min-height` if you also use `display: block;` to overwrite `display: table(-*);`

Comment: After much deliberation and head scratching: yup. Just use plain old height instead. http://codepen.io/squarecandy/full/wWLNAV/

Comment: For me, for some reason, display: table* is the ONLY thing that makes min-height work properly in Firefox. This is really annoying...

Comment: When I got rid of height: 100% for the parent of the element with min-height, all started working properly again. Weird.

Answer (score 15):

The min-height property is supported in all major browsers.

But this property is not working with html tables on firefox.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that it doesn't work in Firefox for any `display: table-*` elements (bug 307866).

Answer (score 2):

When an element's display is set to table, firefox will ignore the min-height property without actually setting the height.

By switching the element to display:block, firefox then respected the min-height property.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `ul`.

The problem is that your `LI`s are floated which causes the parent to not know the height of it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

I have added following and it's worked:

```
body {
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to clear the floating of the nested li tags like this:

```
ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of min-height:50px; just add padding: 25px 0;