# Firefox not rendering min-height

Tags: css, firefox

`min-height` is not working in Firefox, but works in IE, Edge and Chrome

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="min-height:80%; background:#543;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to show the min-height? Pixels is not an option, it needs to be %

Comment: This SO thread might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053206/css-min-height-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox

Comment: That answer shows to use pixels, which **isn't** an option... I can't predict the height of the device viewing the page @hurnhu - I had actually seen that, I promise I did research it first :)

Comment: add `height` style to `body`

Comment: @AnkithAmtange why not? It only affects this one browser?

Comment: My bad. Thats very strange indeed. It seemed more like a CSS problem at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to css

```
body, html {
 height: 100%
}
```

Why ?

because the percent is calculate based on the parent and right now the body and html don't have height

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fz6L792/1/)

Comment: Wow, even with a great explanation... No other answers needed, thank you. I didn't realise it was due to the parent... Thank you.