# When resize divs elements inside show out

Tags: css, resize

[enter image description here][1]I have simple divs for create vertical menu , and show to full this in my website , all it´s perfect working but when i go to resize the window to minimum i see the elements inside go to the right and don´t show in the center and i see really all div don´t resize completly in the moment i go resize windows to this minimun

I see this when testing in firefox , not in others brownsers , all problem it´s when the resize it´s lower than 200¡px , if i put the windows resize some more up of this width , show perfectly , but only happend me in firefox

**You can see the code here :**

https://jsfiddle.net/g7v7t07m/

**The best it´s test in brownser :**

```
<style>



#web_header_menu_boton_1
{
display:block;
position:relative;
min-width:100%;
width:auto;
margin-top:2px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:green;
}

#web_header_menu_boton_2
{
display:block;
position:relative;
min-width:100%;
width:auto;
margin-top:2px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:red;
}

</style>

<div id="web_header_menu_boton_1">MENU TOP</div>
<div id="web_header_menu_boton_2">MENU TOP</div>
<div id="web_header_menu_boton_1">MENU TOP</div>
<div id="web_header_menu_boton_2">MENU TOP</div>
<div id="web_header_menu_boton_1">MENU TOP</div>
```

**Image total resize window see bad :**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Pt2K-f2Sp1R1FYZ21tazczUm8

Comment: so you shut look for questions and answers. try use moz- see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053206/css-min-height-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox

Answer (score 0):

your question is not so clearly for me. maybe adding a picture to show what happend would be great. But i gess you need to write some mozila code if its only in mozilla firefox. Go search in css moz-... (like webkit-... or other ones).

Comment: you can see here  : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Pt2K-f2Sp1R1FYZ21tazczUm8

Comment: And here if no total resize minimun see well https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Pt2K-f2Sp1MGF1eU9qRGxJS00