# 3D Transform Perspective not working until Dev Tools is open CSS

Tags: html, css

The issue only appears in Firefox, the styling won't work until the inspector opens. I assume it has something to do with perspective or transform-style, but nothing I do seems to help

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/JonHerbert/pen/agYOyR?editors=0100)

```
.id-card {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.id-card-inner {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px #bababa;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.id-card:hover .id-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.id-card-front, .id-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
}
.id-card-front {
  z-index: 1;
}
.id-card-back {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.id-card img {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

[Video](https://streamable.com/tqht9)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `height:300px` for `.id-card` it will works

```
.id-card {
  /*height: 100%;*/
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    clear:both;
}
```

[Check the updated codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEdxxx?editors=0100)

Comment: Thank you! I can see now why the children don't 'inherit' the height, but why does this affect the styling from showing until the inspector is on?

Comment: Because min-height is not working in (mozilla) your code for your reference check this answer [why min-height is not working on mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053206/css-min-height-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox)